# If we have many inputs with same name how we can receive the value and insert into the database

Tags: php

I have four input fields named `['institution','Department','Country','City']`. Each input field Is repeated 10 times.

I want to:

1. Receive the value of all input fields using PHP
2. Check which values in the input fields are empty or invalid
3. Ensure that only proper input values are inserted into the database but not all
4. Insert into the database

```html
<input type='text'  value='' name='institution[]' class='form-control'>
<input type='text'  value='' name='department[]' class='form-control'>
<input type='text'  value='' name='city[]' class='form-control'>
<select class='form-control' name='country[]' id='setwidth'>
  <option value='Dubai'></option>
  <option value='Dubai'></option>
  <option value='Dubai'></option>
</select>
```

Comment: try this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`, and you'll see the solution. you don't have "the same name". you have a bunch of fields that PHP will load up as an array of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next is an small example of how to do it, first the HTML form that captures the data in several fields with the same name, second the PHP that gets the data as array :

**test.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="test.php">
      <input type='text' value='aaa' name='institution[]'/>
      <br/>
      <input type='text'             name='institution[]'/>
      <br/>
      <input type='text' value='555' name='institution[]'/>
      <br/>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit'/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
$my_array = $_POST[ "institution" ];
for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $my_array ); $i++ )
  if ( $my_array[ $i ] == "" )
       echo "Index $i is unset.<br/>";
  else echo "Index $i = " . $my_array[ $i ] . "<br/>";
?>
```

Comment: I have four input fields with four different names, each input field is repeated minimum ten times. i was already captured the value of input and also remove the empty strings but i am failed to insert these values into database

Comment: How are you trying to insert the values?

Comment: Can You Give a Example Please

Comment: @NajeedUrRehman : `if ( $my_array[ $i ] != "" ) { "insert into tbl (institution) values (' " . $my_array[ $i ] . " ')"; `

Answer (score 0):

For the HTML part, it is already mentioned, append an array to the name of the field you want to get as a collection, I assume the field `departments`:

```
<input type='text' name='departments[]' />
```

But for the server side, I mean PHP and MySQL:
You have two ways before yourself:

1- You should see if you want to aggregate the data into one record, for instance you have 10 instances of `Department`, and you want to put all of them in one single row/field. In this method, you simply do:

SQL Query:

`insert into table_name (department) values(:department)";`

PHP:
$departments = serialize(get_input($_POST['department']));

Of course you have already validate your form which is not mainly our subject. Also, `get_input()` is a function which you should write to filter your `$_REQUEST` entries. At the end of this post there is a sample of the function.

2- You have a separate table for each multiple-valued field. For instance you have a table named `user_to_departments` with following keys:

```
id | user_id | department
```

And then in your query you have to insert a record for each entry of the query, something such as this:

```
$departments = get_input($_POST['departments']);

foreach($departments as $dep)
{
   db_query("insert into user_to_departments ($user_id, $dep)");   
}
```

The above line puts the value directly into the query, which is not a nice practice and you should always use prepared statement which is greatly supported in MySQLi and PDO.

More on prepared statement: 
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Also, for selecting the queries from such database whose scheme are more standard, you should rely on JOIN statements. More on MySQL JOIN statements: 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Here is a very simple sample function for `get_input()`:

```
function get_input($value)
{
   if(is_array($value))
   {
      foreach($value as $key => $val)
      {  
          $value[$key] = htmlentities(strip_tags($val)); // it allows only html entities and tag-free values
      }
   }
   else
   { 
           $value = htmlentities(strip_tags($value));
   }


   return $value;
}
```